# How to keep a weak reference to an object?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, weak-references

(FYI: This question is half thoretical.  It is not something which I am definatly planning on doing.)

I would like to be able to keep a reference to all the objects that I create.  Maybe like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private static List<Foo> AllMyFoos = new List<Foo>();

    public Foo()
    {
        AllMyFoos.Add(this);
    }
}
```

The trouble with this is that now none of my Foos can ever drop out of focus and be garbage collected.  Is there any way of keeping a referance without getting in the way of the garbage collector?

Ideally I just of a list of Foos that are still being used, not all Foos which have ever been used.

Comment: IMHO if you have a reference, then it can't be garbarge collected, so you should be thinking another way about this.. Maybe if you explain where you want to get theorical we can be more helpfull?

Comment: How is the GC supposed to know the difference. There must be some logic behind what objects should be kept and what objects to garbage collect. If there is some logic you should be able to implement it. IDisposable interface is one way to get rid of unwanted objects. Just remove the object from the static list in the dispose method.

Comment: @gbianchi you are not quite right , there is `WeakRefernce` in .net

Comment: @vittore yes yes, looks like google know about that ;).. I was asking about the theorical thing OP want to get to, but answers already cover up that this exists...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) - it does exactly what it is supposed to. Be careful while  working with it - **you have to check if the reference is still valid every time you dereference it**.

[Tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-weak-references).

---

```
Foo foo = AllMyFoos[index].Target as Foo;
if (foo == null)
{
   // Object was reclaimed, so we can't use it.
}
else
{
   // foo is valid. My theoretical curiosity can be satisfied
}
```

**Warning**: Just because the object hasn't yet been garbage collected doesn't mean someone hasn't called `Dispose` on it, or in some other way put it into a state that it is not prepared to be used again.

Comment: There's also `ConditionalWeakTable<K,V>` too, depending on what the OP's exact requirements are. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is special thing which is named exactly this way - [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)